# Error while deploying Nodes

Tags: corda

I have cloned the Corda Example with Version 3.0. (https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example.git)

While deploying the code through Terminal with with the command "gradlew deployNodes" i am getting following error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':kotlin-source:compileKotlin'.

  > Internal compiler error. See log for more details

Any clue?

Comment: Some compilation error. Check the *client.kt classes. they may have some errors. Intellij may not show all errors in one go. ;)

Comment: Can you check the logs and update the question with the error message?

Comment: Joel - where can see the log?

Comment: here is the link of the scan

https://scans.gradle.com/s/a4jjfashoxrq6/failure?openFailures=WzBd&openStackTraces=WzEseyJfdCI6W10sIl9rIjoidmFsdWVzIn1d#top=0

Comment: I managed to fixed this issue by upgrading my JDK to 162  version.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by using an unsupported JDK version.

The earliest supported version at the time of writing is Oracle JDK 8u131. You can see the supported JDK versions here: https://docs.corda.net/getting-set-up.html#software-requirements.